# Mask Sensitive Information in a 2D Image Using PHP

Tags: php, image-processing, image-masking

I am trying to mask sensitive information such as Name, Email, Mobile Number, Address, DOB from an image / scanned copy of an application using PHP.

Tried using http://image.intervention.io/

```
<?php
// include composer autoload
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Intervention\Image\ImageManager;

$sampleImagePath = 'images/sample-1.png';
$maskedImagePath = 'images/alpha.png';
$outputImagePath = 'output/sample-1.png';

try {

    $manager = new ImageManager(array('driver' => 'imagick'));

    $image = $manager->make($sampleImagePath);

    $image->insert($maskedImagePath, "top-left", 70, 50)->opacity(100);

    $image->save($outputImagePath);
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    var_dump($ex->getMessage());
    exit;
}
?>
```

but identifying particular field coordinates, width and height are getting difficult as the user could have captured images from different angles.

Looking for suggestions from experts to achieve this.

Comment: Do you have any code you can share of what you have tried already?

Comment: Yes, I have a code snippet.